# Resonance frequency and impedance of a piezoelectric element

Tags: electrical-resistance, resonance, piezoelectric

I am reading about piezoelectric elements, and I have some questions in that regard. I have come across a graph showing the impedance as a function of frequency. Some spikes occurs on the graph at some specific frequencies (resonance frequencies). First of all, how do you know wether the resonance frequency of the piezo is where its impedance is lowest or where its impedance is highest ?

My second question is why there exist more than one resonance frequency ?

Answer (score 0):

The multiple spikes may be associated to the multiple mechanical resonances (normal modes of vibrations) excited in your piezoelectric slab at specific frequencies (depending on the geometry of the slab and the coupling direction). Since piezoelectricity couples the mechanical behaviour with the electrical behaviour, what you see in the impedance curve  is the electrical counterpart of these resonances (through a motional impedance). I suggest you study the simple Van Dyke model. It is a good starting point to understand the resonances and the motional impedance.